# Alignment issue when resizing bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a code which has a Bootstrap row with two columns. One with text and the other one with image. I have added another div to align the image to the center when the browser window gets resized using `position:absolute`. Now the image gets aligned but the row does not extend to the image.

[image]
Here is the code..

```
  <div class="container-fluid about">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 description">
            Some text here...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 image">
           <div class="img-container">
              <img src="#" class="img-responsive">
           </div>
      </div>
    </div>    
 </div>
```

Here is the CSS...

```
.about{
  margin-top:60px;
  min-height:300px;
  background-color:#1E8BC3;
}
.about .row {
  max-width:1000px;
  min-height:300px;
}

.about .description{
  padding-top:10%;
  padding-left:5%;
  font-size:16px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}
.about .image{
  padding-top:5%;
  padding-left:0;
  padding-right:5%;
}
.img-container{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.img-container img{
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:250px;
  max-height:200px;
}
```

Please help me with the code.

Comment: Using position:absolute makes the element become out of the flow of the document, all dom elements will ignore the space taken by it.

Comment: @vignesh did u tried `thumbnail` class

Comment: and you should try https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#thumbnails

Comment: Yeah, I tried using thumbnail. It doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the below part and now it works! :)

```
.img-container{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```